# Can I run a Rails 2 and a Rails 3 applications on the same server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I'm trying to figure out if I can run on the same server(I have an AWS running with ubuntu) a Rails 2 and a Rails 3 applications?

Is this possible? Or I'm just dreaming?

Thanks people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Ruby and RubyGems are designed to install and run different version of the same Gem on the same server and Rails it's nothing more than a Gem.

My suggestion is to use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to isolate Gem dependencies and Rails versions. It's quite easy to do, Rails 3 uses Bundler by default. You can use Bunder with Rails 2.3 as well. The instructions are on the Bundler website.

When you deploy your project, Bundler will install the necessary dependencies and you'll be able to run two or more projects with several different versions of Rails on the same machine.

Comment: Simone and what about the ruby version? I have installed ruby 1.9.2 but for the rails 2 apps I will need 1.8.7 version. Do you have any suggestion for that? Can I use RVM in this case?

Comment: Yes, in this case you can use RVM but it's becoming quite complicated because you would need to instruct the web server as well. If you are dealing with different Ruby versions, I suggest you to use separate servers.

Comment: Andres, it depends on your webserver. If you want to use passenger, read this article: http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.  You need a Ruby Version Manager: https://rvm.io/

Comment: The question was about different Rails versions, not Ruby. Even though the task of running multiple apps with different Ruby versions on the same machine is not that trivial and cannot be solved simply by using RVM. It depends on the webserver.